# Confusing Force.com Sites Certification Question

Tags: force.com-sites, dev401

Which statement is true regarding Force.com sites? Choose 3

1   Sites can leverage declarative page layouts as web pages

2   Sites enables developers to build public, unauthenticated websites

3   Sites are built as visualforce pages

4   Sites leverage data and content in a Salesforce org.

I thought the correct answer is 2, 3, 4. But some websites are saying that 1, 3, 4 are the correct answers. Can someone please verify? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the correct answer is 2, 3, 4